# Make list-group-items in adjacent columns same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of Bootstrap columns that contain a panel with a list group inside each.

Each list group consists of the same number of items, however because of differences in the text, the height of each `list-group-item` is different, causing them to mis-align across the page.

I would like each `list-group-item` to align, to get the appearance of a table. I can achieve this by giving the `list-group-item` a height value, but since the text is dynamic and may change this is not a perfect solution.

Ideally, I would like to have a CSS only solution without JavaScript.

My current HTML is below. You may need to open the snippet full screen to avoid Bootstrap column issues.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>People</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in death or permanent disability of employees.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in partial permanent disability, injuries or illness of 3 employees or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Injury or illness resulting in one or more work days lost.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Minor illness or injury to employees resulting in one day's absence.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minor illness or injury to employees with no absent days.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Environment</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Irreversible environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Reversible environment damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mitigable environment damage where restoration activities can be done.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Little environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minimal environmental damage.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Financial</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 1M or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 200,000 but less than 1M.></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 10,000 but less than 200,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 5,000 but les than 10,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: Less than 5,000.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like it to look like using fixed heights:

```css
.list-group-item {
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>People</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in death or permanent disability of employees.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in partial permanent disability, injuries or illness of 3 employees or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Injury or illness resulting in one or more work days lost.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Minor illness or injury to employees resulting in one day's absence.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minor illness or injury to employees with no absent days.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Environment</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Irreversible environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Reversible environment damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mitigable environment damage where restoration activities can be done.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Little environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minimal environmental damage.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Financial</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 1M or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 200,000 but less than 1M.></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 10,000 but less than 200,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 5,000 but les than 10,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: Less than 5,000.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise a (preferably) CSS only way to get each `list-group-item` to align across the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists are in different elements, most of the css only ways that could be used to achieve this are out of the window (margin/padding hack, for example)

What you could do, is to make an educated guess about how many rows the longest text would have on each screen size, and set the min-height of all `.list-group-item`s to that value (i have used `em` unit here, but you can use whatever works for you better).

First do it for the largest screen size, then use media queries ( `@media (max-width: 768px)` for example) to override it for smaller screens.

This would work in all browsers, except in some older versions of IE.

**Note: Please open the snippet in full screen to see its effects on large screen.**

**Update**

Based on the new info you have given, you could do a trick with my solution:

Restrict the maximum length of the text users can enter to a reasonable length (250 characters, for example), and fix the item heights on what height the longest text may result. Use long words in a test text to check how much the line numbers may vary.

```css
.list-group-item {
  min-height:6em; // this is it
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>People</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in death or permanent disability of employees.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in partial permanent disability, injuries or illness of 3 employees or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Injury or illness resulting in one or more work days lost.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Minor illness or injury to employees resulting in one day's absence.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minor illness or injury to employees with no absent days.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Environment</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Irreversible environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Reversible environment damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mitigable environment damage where restoration activities can be done.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Little environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minimal environmental damage.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Financial</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 1M or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 200,000 but less than 1M.></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 10,000 but less than 200,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 5,000 but les than 10,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: Less than 5,000.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I know I can use a fixed height (absolute or minimum). I'm trying to find a way to do it without specifying a heights since I don't know the length of the text (it's user entered).

Comment: And as I said in my answer, there is no good css-only way for your case.

Comment: How much text the users are allowed to enter?

Comment: Currently unrestrained which, I agree, is another solution.

Answer (score -1):

**You can do something like this by adding media queries.**

```
.panel{ height: 400px;}/*set height according to the first panel*/
```

Do this for all screen size devices as shown below.

You can also add some padding (top & bottom) to list items of Panel-. 

 and Panel-3. 
*Happy coding :-)*

```css
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.panel{
height: 400px ! important;}
  .list-group-2 .list-group-item{
  padding-top: 18px! important;
  padding-bottom: 18px! important;}
  
  .list-group-3 .list-group-item{
  padding-top: 18px! important;
  padding-bottom: 18px! important;}    
     
}


/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.panel{
height: 510px ! important;}
  .list-group-2 .list-group-item{
  padding-top: 16px! important;
  padding-bottom: 16px! important;}
  
  .list-group-3 .list-group-item{
  padding-top: 16px! important;
  padding-bottom: 16px! important;}
}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.panel{
height: 510px ! important;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>People</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in death or permanent disability of employees.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in partial permanent disability, injuries or illness of 3 employees or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Injury or illness resulting in one or more work days lost.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Minor illness or injury to employees resulting in one day's absence.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minor illness or injury to employees with no absent days.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Environment</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-2">
          <li class="list-group-item">Irreversible environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Reversible environment damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mitigable environment damage where restoration activities can be done.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Little environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minimal environmental damage.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Financial</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-3">
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 1M or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 200,000 but less than 1M.></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 10,000 but less than 200,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 5,000 but les than 10,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: Less than 5,000.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to read full question first. OP already said that he can give fix height  but text is dynamic so i don't want to give. Thank you

Comment: Also, each item needs to line up with the respective items in each panel, not just the overall height.

Answer (score -1):

try this

fix the height for list-group.

```css
.list-group
   {
   height:380px;
 }
.list-group-item {
  height:70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>People</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in death or permanent disability of employees.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Results in partial permanent disability, injuries or illness of 3 employees or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Injury or illness resulting in one or more work days lost.
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            Minor illness or injury to employees resulting in one day's absence.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minor illness or injury to employees with no absent days.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Environment</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Irreversible environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Reversible environment damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Mitigable environment damage where restoration activities can be done.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Little environmental damage.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Minimal environmental damage.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Financial</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 1M or more.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 200,000 but less than 1M.></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 10,000 but less than 200,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: 5,000 but les than 10,000.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Amount of loss: Less than 5,000.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question that's how I *am* doing it but I'd prefer not to hardcode any particular height.